# :hover function just on selected inner parts of a DIV

Tags: css, hover

When hovering over the "div.c-header-action-bar" bar, another bar ("div.test") should appear underneath. This currently works so far, but the hover function should be limited a bit. The white X to close the bar ("btn - reset o-alert__close") should be excluded from the hover. The hover should only apply to "o-sub-headline" and "fa fa-info-circle". I've already tried it, but I can't get it. Could someone please help me there?

Here are two pictures of the bar open and closed:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/91JvN.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cj2Il.png

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

 <style>
 div.test {
 background-color: #619982;
 display: none;
 text-align: center;
 font-family: arial;
 font-weight: 700;
 letter-spacing: .1rem;
 margin: 0;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 color: #fff;
 flex-grow: 1;
 font-size: 1.5rem;
 line-height: 2rem;
 padding: .5rem 0;
 }

.c-header-action-bar:hover + div.test {
 display: block;
}


 .c-header {
 position: fixed
 z-index: 10030 !important;
 }

 .test {
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 10031 !important;
 width: 100%;
 }
 </style>




 <div class="c-header-action-bar" data-js-controller="alert" data-visibility-cookie-controlled="true" 
 style="background: #619982 ;">

 <p class="o-sub-headline">Wir geben die MWSt-Senkung an Sie weiter! Jetzt 3% Rabatt mit Code <span 
 style="background-color: #ffffff; color: #619982 ;">&nbsp;MWST16&nbsp;</span> sichern!&nbsp;
 <i class="fa fa-info-circle" style="font-size:17px;color:white"></i>
  </p>

 <button class="btn--reset o-alert__close">
 <svg class="o-icon o-icon--small"><use xlink:href="#small--close" /></svg>
 </button>
 </div>


 <div class="test">Sie erhalten 3% Rabatt auf alle Artikel aus unserem Online-Shop, auch auf 
 reduzierte Artikel. Geschenkkarten sind von der Aktion ausgeschlossen.<br> Der Aktionscode "MWST16" 
 ist nicht mit anderen Aktionscodes kombinierbar.</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will resolve your issue.

**Please Note:** To do this, we have to move `<div class ="test">` inside.

Test it with [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dLstcuh1/)

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<style>
  div.test {
    background-color: #619982;
    display: none;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: arial;
    font-weight: 700;
    letter-spacing: .1rem;
    margin: 0;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #fff;
    flex-grow: 1;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    line-height: 2rem;
    padding: .5rem 0;
  }
  
  .o-sub-headline:hover~div.test {
    display: block;
  }
  
  .c-header {
    position: fixed z-index: 10030 !important;
  }
  
  .test {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 10031 !important;
    width: 100%;
  }
</style>

<div class="c-header-action-bar" data-js-controller="alert" data-visibility-cookie-controlled="true" style="background: #619982 ;padding-top: 50px">
  <p class="o-sub-headline">Wir geben die MWSt-Senkung an Sie weiter! Jetzt 3% Rabatt mit Code <span style="background-color: #ffffff; color: #619982 ;">&nbsp;MWST16&nbsp;</span> sichern!&nbsp;
    <i class="fa fa-info-circle" style="font-size:17px;color:white"></i>
  </p>
 <button class="btn--reset o-alert__close">
  <svg class="o-icon o-icon--small"><use xlink:href="#small--close" /></svg>
 </button>
  <div class="test">Sie erhalten 3% Rabatt auf alle Artikel aus unserem Online-Shop, auch auf reduzierte Artikel. Geschenkkarten sind von der Aktion ausgeschlossen.<br> Der Aktionscode "MWST16" ist nicht mit anderen Aktionscodes kombinierbar.</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hello BOZ,
thanks for your reply.
Unfortunately, it still doesn't work as it should.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/0VfF8.png
-> There is a large empty space at the top.

                       
https://i.stack.imgur.com/d8WuG.png
-> The info text appears in the bar and does not expand downwards.

Can you maybe help again?